# How to view organic traffic landing pages in GA4 ? Used to be able to find in GA3

Tags: google-analytics, utm-parameters

I was using UTM tracking to track traffic from Google Local / Google My Business (GMB) to a website.

More info can be found on this [here](https://searchlabdigital.com/blog/using-utm-tracking-in-google-my-business/), but in short, you place a UTM tag at the end of your website's URL in GMB and then in Google Analytics, you can view "landing pages" to see your GMB traffic.

This works fine in Google Analytics 3, but ive just transfered to Google Analytics 4 and cant see this data, any idea where i can find it in GA4 ?

In GA3 i could see this data under using the following.

[image: screenshot from GA3]

But in GA4 when i view "traffic acquisition" i cant drill down further into "organic"

[image: screenshot from GA4]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a Landing Page report available in your Library

1. Click on Reports, then click on Library (bottom of the left side menu.)
2. locate the Life Cycle collection in the carousel under Collections, and click on Edit Collection
3. on the right side, scroll down until you find Landing Page. Drag it to the Acquisition or Engagement Section on the left side
   [image: Add Landing Page Report to Life Cycle collection]

4. Save your changes (I usually click "Save to Current Collection when adding the Landing Page report)
5. Go to the Landing Page report, and under the Report title, there is a little filter option, click on it. The right side panel will open. Look for Session Source/Medium... or if you're just looking for Organic, you can filter by Session Default Channel Grouping

[image: filter by session default channel group]
[image: filter the landing page report by session source/medium]

6. click save, and it's updated. Unfortunately, you will have to do this every time unless you build out custom exploration and add it to the side menu.

Comment: Great first answer

Comment: @RohitGupta thank you!